# HD Video Playback issue with android things

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, exoplayer, android-things

Has anyone been able to successfully play a HD video using Android Things on a Raspberry Pi? If so was there anything special you had to do to get it to work? If not does any one know why it isn't working?

I made a simple video player that plays a local video from disk. The app runs fine on a phone but with android things maximum frames are getting dropped.

I am using ExoPlayer for the video playback and the same issue is observed when Media Player is used.Hardware acceleration is also enabled in the manifest file.

Comment: I’ve been running the ExoPlayer example code; none of the sample videos play full-screen for me without dropped frames, at any resolution. I tried installing Raspbian onto the same Pi and viewing YouTube videos in Chromium; performance seemed a bit better full-screen but I still had dropped frames. When in a less-than-full-screen Chromium window I managed to get smooth playback.

Adding HW acceleration to the ExoPlayer manifest didn’t have any effect for me.

Comment: OK, I managed to get best performance by lowering the resolution of my playback to the 640x360 examples in ExoPlayerDemo, turning off audio when playing, and dropping the resolution of my Android Things setup to 640x480. With this I can play the H264 or VP9 YouTube DASH videos all the way through without a single dropped frame.

Not putting this as an answer because it's not HD.